# Problem with time format

Tags: java, android, time

I wrote the following code to get the time

```
public String getTime() {
    final Calendar cld = Calendar.getInstance();
    String time = cld.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + (cld.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    try {
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").parse(time);
        time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return time;
}
```

This always give me time like

11:59

01:07

But I need in 24 hrs format like:

11:59

13:07

How to change the code.

Comment: What was the _actual_ time when you got the 01:07 output? Was it 1:07am, or 1:07pm?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `HOUR_OF_DAY` instead of `HOUR`.

Comment: where in Calendar.HOUER_OF_DAY?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Calendar.HOUR = Field number for get and set indicating the hour of the morning or afternoon. HOUR is used for the 12-hour clock. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the HOUR is 10.

Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY = Field number for get and set indicating the hour of the day. HOUR_OF_DAY is used for the 24-hour clock. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the HOUR_OF_DAY is 22.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
String time = hour + ":" + minute;
```

Answer (score 0):

HH:mm is correct. 01:07 is 1am and 13:07 is 1pm. Wait until 1pm and see or create a date object and test it.